# ajax vs src script request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

today when I exploring Google API, I saw in their sample code, they simply request a url by doing

```
<script src="src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1.."></script>
```

Sad for me, my first thought before seeing this was ajax. Now I'm confused, the different with this 2. I can't do request as above as I need to add users' input within it.

like

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1&"'+user+'"
```

so if I use ajax, will achieve the same? sorry that I haven't try, but I'm still in confusion what's the diff btw them even I try.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<script src>` to retrieve JSON data is a technique called JSONP.  It gets around cross-site scripting limitations (your browser may block an AJAX request if it's to a different domain than the page it comes from; it won't block a script load that way).  The disadvantage is that you can't do other HTTP methods (PUT, POST, DELETE, etc) - only GET.  Also, as @FelixKing pointed out, the server has to support it - if you just drop a JSON blob as the contents of `<script>` element, that's not going to do you any good - it has to be sent to a callback.  If the API supports JSONP, it will usually take a `callback=functionName` parameter, and the emitted script will be `functionName({... JSON blob here ...})`.

You can still make it dynamic to add things like your user parameter, however.  You just need to use Javascript to add the `<script>` element to the page, instead of hard-coding it into the HTML:

```
var user = "someone";
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.src = 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1&user="+user
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

But I don't know what you're doing exactly, or if that call even supports JSONP; that's just an example of using Javascript to dynamically add a `<script>` element.  Details are up to you.

Comment: Edited to add example, @user3522742.

Comment: JSONP can also only be used if the server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will acchieve the same if you do something like this:

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyCVAXiUzRYsML1Pv6RwSG1&"+user, function(response) {
  // process the result here
});
```

As additional note: the "<script src=https://www.googleapis..." thing is a method used by ajax implementation if other methods fails (XMLHttpRequest, for example), so, you can (should) relay on ajax a let the library do what is better for your context (this is good for cross-browser support)

Comment: tried, nothing happen.. check the network tab, nothing happen too.. no error in the console. jquery included properly.. hmm

Comment: That is not the approach I suggested